# How to automatically restore window arrangement from last time in iTerm?

Tags: macos, iterm2

I have two old Macs, both have iTerm2 installed and could automatically restore window arrangement (tabs with different directories and colors) from last time after launch.  I forget what configuration I've made for both.

Now I'm setting up a new Mac with iTerm2, but could never get "automatically restore window arrangement from last time" working there.

What I've tried:

1. Compared with the working ones, check and set the preferences one by one;
2. Cloned the working "`~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`";
3. `Preferences` -> `Profiles` -> `General` -> `Working Directory` -> `Reuse previous session's directory` (but I think this impacts when you open a new tab, not for launch);
4. `Menu` -> `Window` -> `Save Window Arrangement` -> and `save it as default`.  But in this case, every time if I launch from start, iTerm always restore fixed window arrangement from the save.  I don't want to save any pattern, I just want restore whatever I have from last time.

All the things I've tried could not make it work.  Could anyone tell me what should I do please?  Thanks a lot.

iTerm version: `iTerm2-1_0_0_20140112`

Comment: One more hint: both of the working Macs, I haven't used any AppleScript, just checked some options in the preferences.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In iTerm2's preferences (`Cmd + ,`), change General > Startup from `Open Default Window Arrangement` to `Use System Window Restoration Setting`.

In System Preferences, turn off General > Close windows when quitting an app.

Comment: Thanks @George, that solves the problem!  So the trick is to turn off one option in System Preferences which is outside app config.

Comment: In 2019, iTerm v3+ I had to just go to Preferences -> Arrangements and click "Set Default" on your created arrangement (save it first by clicking cmd+shift+S)

Answer (score 26):

In 2019 (iTerm v3.2.9), what works for me is:

1. Save your current arrangement by clicking CMD + shift + S (or go Window -> Save Window Arrangement.
2. Now go to iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Arrangements -> select your arrangement in the list of arrangements -> Click "Set Default" at the bottom.
3. Preferences -> General -> startup to Opend default window arrangement

Now when you reopen iTerm at any point it will open your new arrangement.

Comment: This in my opinion should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer requires a system setting change and this one doesn't. One comment though: It's also necessary to set `Preferences -> General -> startup` to `Opend default window arrangement`

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a program designed to solve this pain point for myself, which allows you to create pre-defined layouts of panes and commands (for different projects/setups etc.) and then load them in iTerm whenever you want.

It is called iTermocil, and you can download it (and the source code) via Github: https://github.com/TomAnthony/itermocil.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/TomAnthony/itermocil/issues/97